# Reputation disappeared mid session

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, reputation

I looked up a VBA editor problem -- and found it asked and answered accurately twice.

I upvoted the first question's answer, located the second question's answer, and went to upvote it, only to be told that I have to have 15 reputation points to upvote!

It appears that all record of my ever having HAD any reputation or privileges has disappeared. I tried recalculating it, but that produced no change.

I don't know how many reputation points I had -- not a lot, but some. I don't hang out on SO answering questions, but when I occasionally spot questions I can answer. And, of course, it let me upvote that first time.

If upvoting consumes reputation, I couldn't find any indication of this anywhere, nor record of having consumed reputation! If that's what's going on, it sure could use more visibility.

I'm the only SO reader at this IPv4 address (my home), and of course at this IPv6 address (though I doubt IPv6 is being used, sigh, but my router is capable).

I don't care overmuch, but it would have been nice to reward the author of the second answer and to alert readers to its validity.

I just noticed that the answer of the second answer is the same as the author of the first. If this triggered your filters, your filters are crazy. Two upvotes for two answers for the same author is not only reasonable, it's also something you're likely to not even notice.

Comment: What?! Am I missing something here? How much reputation did you have before?

Comment: From your description it looks like someone or something triggered a reputation recalculation on your account after the first vote and before the second. You probably have some deleted content (that I can't see) that was up-voted.

Comment: Upvoting does not consume reputation.  Looking at your account, I only see the rep recalc that you initiated, so it's not caused by a rep recalc.  However, I only see two answers with no upvotes, so it looks like you just don't have any rep at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/556742/bob-kerns -- I guess that's you as well?

Comment: Balpha -- yes, that's me as well -- but my profile claims they're all me. And I didn't do *anything* to switch between "me"s.

But it looks like the most likely explanation is that somehow there are two mes, and somehow, without any relevant action on my part, it switched me. Same browser.

Sorry about not posting it on Meta -- I realized after I posted I had gotten switched back to non-meta while checking on things.

How can I get to be just me?

Answer (score 3):

You had 2 user accounts, one of which was from a browser session long ago that actually had rep.  I've merged them and you should now have that rep on [your primary account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556742/bob-kerns), enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I can see two answers and a question in your profile. All have 0 upvotes and 0 downvotes. And your account has 1 rep which seems alright. Also you have 0 votes cast.

There are several ways to lose rep, which can push you below a certain privilege. For example:

- vote, accept withdrawal
- downvotes
- deleted posts (although this needs a rep recalc).

Did you ever had 15 or more reputation? If not, then you probably had a glitch in the system that let you vote.

If you think you should have more questions asked and more answers given, then there is probably something wrong with your account. PLease mail team@stackoverflow.com for help if this is the case.

Comment: Yes. In addition to 1 rep on SO and 1 rep on SO, I have 31 on SO.

http://stackoverflow.com/users/556742/bob-kerns

Thanks to @balpha for spotting that!

I shall follow your suggestion of mailing to team@stackoverflow.com. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: BTW, it is worth mentioning -- most weird technical questions I have can be answered by a bit of googling -- and the most common source of the answers is StackOverflow. It's an impressive achievement!